LAMMPS thermodynamic integration giving wrong results
I am trying to compute solvation free energy of methanol in SPC\E water. I am using LAMMPS for that. When I try to switch off the electrostatic interactions to get $dU/d\lambda$ only for the electrostatics, I am getting a very wrong curve.

I am including the lammps input file that I am using for one $\lambda$ ($\lambda = 0.7$)
# -- Initialise system --
units real
atom_style full

# -- read data --
read_data system.data
displace_atoms all random 0.5 0.5 0.5 21344

# -- set charges --
# water
set  type  1  charge  -0.8476
set  type  2  charge  0.4238
# methanol
set  type  3  charge  -0.683
set  type  4  charge  0.418
set  type  5  charge  0.04
set  type  6  charge  0.145

# -- non bonded interactions --
include "ffnonbonded.settings"

# -- kspace --
kspace_style pppm 0.00001

# -- bonded interaction
include "ffbonded.settings"

# -- make groups --
group spc type 1:2
group ow  type 1
group met type 3:6

# -- write ff data --
write_data ff.data pair ij

# -- water shake --
fix myshake all shake 0.0001 10 100 b 1 3 4 a 4

# -- neighbour list --
neighbor 2.0 bin
neigh_modify every 1 delay 0 check yes

# -- compute TI --
variable  lj   equal  1
variable  dlj  equal  1
variable  ks   equal  0.7
variable  dks  equal  1
variable  c    equal  0.7
variable  dc   equal  1
compute myTI all ti lj/cut/soft * v_lj v_dlj coul/long/soft * v_c v_dc kspace * v_ks v_dks
 
# -- simulation protocol --
# EM
minimize 0.0 0.0 1000 10000
write_data postem.data pair ij

# run a nvt equilibriation
timestep 2
velocity all create 300.0 21423623
fix thermo0 all langevin 300 300 100.0 89027 
fix relax0  all nve 
thermo_style custom step temp pe ke press density  
thermo 10
dump myDump2 all custom 100 equil_nvt.lammpstrj id mol type xu yu zu
run 5000
unfix thermo0
unfix relax0

# equilibriate pressure
timestep 2
velocity all create 300.0 21423623
fix thermo1 all langevin 300 300 100.0 89027 
fix relax1   all  nph iso 0.986923 0.986923 2000.0
thermo_style custom step temp pe ke press density 
thermo 10
dump myDump3 all custom 100 equil_npt.lammpstrj id mol type x y z
run 50000
unfix thermo1
unfix relax1

# prod
timestep 2
fix thermo2 all langevin 300 300 100.0 89027 
fix relax2   all  nph iso 0.986923 0.986923 2000.0
thermo_style custom step temp pe ke press density c_myTI
thermo 10
dump myDump4 all custom 100 prod.lammpstrj id mol type x y z 
dump myDump5 ow h5md 10 dump_h5md.h5 position box yes
run 200000
write_data prod.data nocoeff

My question is, of course, what is causing this? Am I not using compute TI correctly? Am I not scaling the potential correctly?
Thanks and regards

+1. Welcome to our community.

How do you know that your simulation duration (under one nanosecond in total??) is sufficient?

Hey, sorry I totally missed the comment. I was testing this method which is why I have small time. However, running for 50 ns does not change anything at all.
